# Can't verify contract on etherscan - unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)

Tags: etherscan, contract-verification

As the title says I cannot verify my smart contract on Etherscan. I read all the solutions from similar threads with no luck. I'm getting the following error :

```
 Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
 Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : AtariToken, ERC20Interface, SafeMath
 But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)

Compiler Version: v0.6.8+commit.0bbfe453
Optimization Enabled: True
Runs: 200
ByteCode (what we are looking for):
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{ipfs}64736f6c634300060800330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

- vs what we got -

We tried looking for a match from the list of compiled contract bytecode outputs (as listed below), but was unable to find an exact match.

1) AtariToken
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{ipfs}64736f6c634300060800330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

2) SafeMath
60566023600b82828239805160001a607314601657fe5b30600052607381538281f3fe73000000000000000000000000000000000000000030146080604052600080fdfe{ipfs}64736f6c634300060800330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Here's a link to my smart contract: 
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x1a0699201b5549328c5eb5332fc07dbc888df60b#code

Some solutions suggested a problem with the ABI in case you use constructor arguments. On my last contract I had constructor arguments, and tried the solution without any results. But for this contract I didn't specify any value for my constructor argument, so my ABI has a value of0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, and hardcoded the totalSupply value in my code, however I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: How does your etherscan link help if your contract isn't verified? We'll need its source code if you're expecting us to give it a try.

Comment: aha sorry I didn't know that. I'll update the thread with the source code

Comment: I just noticed that the contract in the link that you've posted **IS** verified, so it's not quite clear what problem exactly it is that you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Since, my post length is over the allowed limits, I am posting here my contract's source code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
interface ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

contract AtariToken is ERC20Interface {

    string public constant name = "AtariToken";
    string public constant symbol = "ATAR";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 0;

    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event RegistrationSuccessful(uint256 nonce);
    event RegistrationFailed(uint256 nonce);

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    uint256 totalSupply_ = 7777100000;

    mapping (string => address) addressTable;

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    constructor( uint256 _totalSupply) public{
        totalSupply_ = _totalSupply;
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function balanceOf(string memory tokenOwner) public view returns (uint) {
        address userAddress;
        userAddress = addressTable[tokenOwner];
        return balances[userAddress];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(string memory receiver, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
        address receiverAddress;
        receiverAddress = addressTable[receiver];
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[receiverAddress] = balances[receiverAddress].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiverAddress, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(string memory delegate, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
        address delegateAddress;
        delegateAddress = addressTable[delegate];
        allowed[msg.sender][delegateAddress] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegateAddress, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function allowance(string memory owner, string memory delegate) public view returns (uint) {
        address ownerAddress;
        ownerAddress = addressTable[owner];
        address delegateAddress;
        delegateAddress = addressTable[delegate];
        return allowed[ownerAddress][delegateAddress];
    }

     function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);    
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(string memory owner, string memory buyer, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
        address ownerAddress;
        ownerAddress = addressTable[owner];
        address buyerAddress;
        buyerAddress = addressTable[buyer];

        require(numTokens <= balances[ownerAddress]);    
        require(numTokens <= allowed[ownerAddress][msg.sender]);

        balances[ownerAddress] = balances[ownerAddress].sub(numTokens);
        allowed[ownerAddress][msg.sender] = allowed[ownerAddress][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[buyerAddress] = balances[buyerAddress].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(ownerAddress, buyerAddress, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function registerUser(string memory user, uint256 nonce) public returns (bool) {
        if (addressTable[user] == address(0)) {
            addressTable[user] = msg.sender;
            emit RegistrationSuccessful(nonce);
            return true;
        } else {
            emit RegistrationFailed(nonce);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

library SafeMath { 
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      assert(b <= a);
      return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = a + b;
      assert(c >= a);
      return c;
    }
}
```